# How to express "to hit someone or something with a string- or wire-form object such as a belt, rope, whip, cable, etc"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> **[whip](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/whip)**: 1 [transitive] to hit someone or something with a whip
>
> He whipped the horse into a canter.

---

Now, I will change the above definition a little bit to "**to hit someone or something with a string- or wire-form object such as a belt, rope, whip, cable, etc**".

**Which verbs express that action?**

I am not sure if I can say "**He whipped me with a belt / cable**" because the verb "**whip**" is to mean "**to hit with a whip, not with other string-form things such as a belt or cable**"?

Comment: Yes, you can. _Whip_ can mean 'hit as though with a whip'. There's even an expression [_to pistol-whip_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistol-whipping) meaning 'to beat someone with an unloaded hand-gun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred dictionary has this definition for the verb *to whip*:

> beat (a person or animal) with a whip **or similar instrument**, especially as a punishment or to urge them on.

So yes, the verb can be used for any weapon, not just "a whip". Interestingly, hitting someone with the butt of a gun is called "pistol-whipping".